# Sort my datagridview by two columns

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I have searched but couldt find the way on visual basic 2010 language. I have a datagridview named ogretmenlerdatagridview. I'm trying to SORT the Datagridview (unbound) by two columns. For example:

It needs to sort by column 1. then by Column 2.

**column1**     **column 2**

4--------------Selim
1--------------Mehmet
3--------------Dilek
4--------------Ali
2--------------Ziya
3--------------Mesut
3--------------Eren
5--------------Turkan
2 -------------Fatma

So sorting it should produce the following:

**column1**     **column 2**

1--------------Mehmet
2--------------Fatma
2--------------Ziya
3--------------Dilek
3--------------Eren
3--------------Mesut
4--------------Ali
4--------------Selim
5 -------------Turkan

i use this code
`OgretmenlerDataGridView.Sort(OgretmenlerDataGridView.Columns(0), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

OgretmenlerDataGridView.Sort(OgretmenlerDataGridView.Columns(1), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)`

It does not work. I looked up everywhere, there are lots of knowledge, but i couldnt succeded none of them. Can you please help me...

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find, I think you are going to have to do it manually. I know that if you have a collection of items, you can use LINQ to do a Sort in the following manner. In this case you would be sorting by FirstName, then by Last Name. There are also methods for sorting in descending order as well. But again I don't think you can do it by using the DataGridView's Sort method. I think that only allows for one column.

```
    myData.OrderBy(i=>i.FirstName).ThenBy(i=>LastName);
```

Comment: Thanks... I turned the datagridview to bound and sprt it by OgretmenlerBindingSource.Sort = "Column1, Column2" it works now.